# Is there an attribute to force a method to run on the main thread in WinForms?

Tags: multithreading, winforms

I work on an application with thousands of methods scattered throughout the code base that should be invoked on the main thread. Many classes unnecessarily derive from a UI control of some sort and as a result, invoking methods or properties may raise cross threading exceptions.

I want to stop this problem without changing everything by doing one of two things:

1. Adding comments to methods and properties which require they be invoked on the main thread. This is lame but must be done.
2. I was hoping to add an attribute of some sort to automatically push requests onto the main thread.

Is the following possible and if so, how might I be able to do this.

```
public class MyCustomClass : Form
{
    [MustInvokeOnMainThread]
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return ... }
    }

    [MustInvokeOnMainThread]
    public void MyMethod(string x, int y)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class NotOnMainThreadClass
{
    MyCustomClass form;

    ...

    public void Method()
    {
        // can this call automatically be invoked on main thread?
        form.MyMethod("asdf", 0);
    }
}
```

Is there something equivalent to `[MustInvokeOnMainThread]`? I am tired of writing code like this:

```
public void Method()
{
    if (form.InvokeRequired)
    {
        from.Invoke(new Action(Method));
        return;
    }

    form.MyMethod("asdf", 0);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no such thing

Comment: See this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37642/Avoiding-InvokeRequired

Comment: David, I am so sorry for the HUGE delay in responding to your comments. Thank you for your feedback, you are quite right: there is no way to do this. I wish you could posted an answer to this question as I would accept it. Also, thank you for your codeproject link---very helpful. I'll try to convince the guys here to use what it offers!

Comment: OK, I turned my comments into an answer. Not the most insightful answer I ever wrote, but there you go. You asked for it. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing. The best you can do to reduce the boiler-plate, probably, is to wrap the boiler-plate up in a helper. This CodeProject article gives you an example of that: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37642/Avoiding-InvokeRequired